# Disabling the nexus-one proximity/position sensor?

Tags: nexus-one, sensors

I think my nexus one is trying to be too smart. For each incoming call the phone stops ringing as soon as I pick it up. That's perfectly fine as long as the phone is sitting on my desk, but when I'm out there the phone is most likely in my jeans front pocket and I end up missing every single call. My guess is that the phone stops ringing/vibrating immediately. Is there a way to dumb it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed any custom calling app? I am sure that this is not the case on my default stock calling app.

Comment: I'm sure I've been missing lots of calls, just guessing at explanations. The obvious one (I can't hear the phone) sounds dubious...

Comment: After a couple of informal tests it seems the correct explanation is the most obvious: I just can't hear the thing ringing. Time to fiddle with volume/ringtone.

Answer (score 1):

In HTC Wildfire there is option in `Settings -> Sound & display`  `Quiet ring on pickup (Reduce ring volume when I move phone`). It might be the same option or similar in nearby.

Comment: My nexus-one came with the stock Eclair UI, that option seems specific to htc phones with Sense (or maybe it was added in Froyo?)